# jQuery Object doesn't support property or method trim() in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

What's up with the jQuery trim method??

```
jQuery('#Reminders').attr('value').trim()
```

Object doesn't support property or method 'trim'

```
jQuery('#Reminders').attr('value')
```

"5,1,1"

```
$('#Reminders').attr('value').split(',')

[5,1,1]
[0]: "5"
[1]: "1"
[2]: "1"
```

I don't have these woes in FireFox or Chrome ... only IE 9.0.  Is there something special about trim()  ... I didn't get the memo .

Answer (score 92, accepted):

IE doesn't have a `string.trim()` method.

Instead, you can call jQuery's `$.trim(str)`.

Answer (score 10):

You can add trim() method on String object, for browsers without support for this method (IE alike).

Simply add these lines before you call trim() method:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}
```

Comment: So you don't overwrite the `trim` method if it already exists, you can do:  `String.prototype.trim = String.prototype.trim || function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
}`

Answer (score 6):

`trim()` is not invoked like that in a jQuery context.

Once you call `attr()`, that's the end of jQuery chaining. See http://api.jquery.com/attr/

To do this, do:

```
jQuery.trim(jQuery('#Reminders').attr('value'));
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here with IE not having the `trim()` method. I solved by adding the `trim()` if it doesn't exist.

```
(function(str) {
    if (typeof(str.prototype.trim) === 'undefined') {
        str.prototype.trim = function() {
            return $.trim(this);
        };
    }
})(String);
```

Works great.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with jquery. Attr is returning a string. What it means is that IE doesn't have a trim method on string.